# Angular Resource Saves in a For/While loop one after another

Tags: angularjs, spring-data-neo4j

I need to save specification items(specitems) from a list in a for/while loop but they have to happen one after another, as in a the code below. In my code firstly I save the specification class get its id (cid) and then start saving the specification items that belong to the specification class. The code below is working fine but its only for a limited number of iterations. If not caring the next save to happen after the other my spring-neo4j backend does some weird stuff i.e. saves the specitems as nodes but not their relationships with the specclass. Propably something is going wrong there as well!?

```
if ($scope.specitems[0]){
    $scope.specitems[0].specClass = cid;
    spClass = new SpecItemService($scope.specitems[0]);
    $scope.specitems.splice(0, 1);
    spClass.$save(function(data) {
        if ($scope.specitems[0]){
            $scope.specitems[0].specClass = cid;
            spClass = new SpecItemService($scope.specitems[0]);
            $scope.specitems.splice(0, 1);
            spClass.$save(function(data) {
                $log.warn("Saved: "+data.name);
                if ($scope.specitems[0]){
                    $scope.specitems[0].specClass = cid;
                    spClass = new SpecItemService($scope.specitems[0]);
                    $scope.specitems.splice(0, 1);
                    spClass.$save(function(data) {
                        $log.warn("Saved: "+data.name);
                        if ($scope.specitems[0]){
                            $scope.specitems[0].specClass = cid;
                            spClass = new SpecItemService($scope.specitems[0]);
                            $scope.specitems.splice(0, 1);
                            spClass.$save(function(data) {
                                $log.warn("Saved: "+data.name);
                            });                    
                        };
                   });                    
               };
           });                    
       };
   });                    
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create some method and call it once and once again (by recursive way) from the `$save` callback.

Something like:

```
$scope.loop = function(){
 if ($scope.specitems[0]){
    spClass.$save(function(data) {
       //....
       $scope.loop();
 });
 }     
}
```